# Puppeteer on clicking <input type="submit" /> redirects to a different url than expected

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to submit a form but I'm getting an issue. There is a form on this page: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx/ . After clicking on the submit button, it displays a new page with the returned data here: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp . It works when doing manually. But when running on puppeteer, after form submission it goes to this url: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx/query.asp and hence displays a 404 page.

Here is my code snippet:

```
async function clickDOT(page) {
  const element = (
    await page.$x(
      "/html/body[1]/form[1]/p[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/label[1]"
    )
  )[0];

  element.click();
}
async function enterDOT(page) {
  const element = (
    await page.$x(
      "/html/body[1]/form[1]/p[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/input[1]"
    )
  )[0];
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

  element.click();
  await element.type("2092172", { delay: 100 });
}
async function submitDOT(page) {
    const element = (
      await page.$x(
        "/html/body[1]/form[1]/p[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[1]/input[1]"
      )
    )[0];

    await page.waitForTimeout(120);
    element.click();
}
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    product: "chrome",
    args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
    // ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    slowMo: 10,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx/");
  await clickDOT(page);
  await enterDOT(page);
  const har = new puppeteerHar(page);
  await har.start({ path: "results.har" });

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    submitDOT(page), // trigger a navigation
  ]);
  await har.stop();
  await page.screenshot({ path: "./1.png" });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Initial page:**
[image]

**Expected output (achieved when doing manually):**
[image]

**Actual output:**
[image]

Comment: Remember that your links are guaranteed to become 404s, either sooner or later, so make sure to include all the code invovled in your post as an [mcve] (which, admittedly, means you're on the hook for turning the code you're trying to work with into something that'll run on its own. Thankfully, dev tools' "copy outer HTML" helps make that quite a lot easier than it used to be. No need for that entire server, get the HTML, drop only the form and its submit button into a new boilerplate html file, change the `action` URL, and now you can run it locally -but *not* from file- and see what happens)